# Relation between Two measures

Tags: real-analysis

How to show Lebesgue stieltjes  measure is a constant times of Lebesgue measure on B(R).
I am thinking of taking an unit interval [0 1] and divide it into r parts interval and using translation invariant. Then I couldn't go further.

Comment: Depends on how those measures are defined.

Comment: The real question is if m is a measure on B(R) such that m (a+ I) = m(I) for all a and for all right -semi closed interval  I in R then how to  show m is the constant times lebesgue measure.